# Python Apscheduler cron job from loop doesn't do all different versions

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler

I've got a function which gets and stores something from an exchange every minute. I run the functions using the (normally excellent) [APScheduler](https://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/). Unfortunately, when I add cron jobs from a loop, it doesn't seem to work as I expect it to.

I've got a little list with a couple strings, for which I want to run the getAndStore function. I could do this like so:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
apsched = Scheduler()
apsched.start()
apsched.add_cron_job(lambda: getAndStore('A'), minute='0-59')
apsched.add_cron_job(lambda: getAndStore('B'), minute='0-59')
apsched.add_cron_job(lambda: getAndStore('C'), minute='0-59')
```

This works fine, but since I'm a programmer and I love to automate stuff, I do this:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
def getAndStore(apiCall):
    # does a call to the api using apiCall as a value
    # and stores it in the DB.
    print apiCall

apiCalls = ['A', 'B', 'C']

apsched = Scheduler()
apsched.start()
for apiCall in apiCalls:
    print 'Start cron for: ', apiCall
    apsched.add_cron_job(lambda: getAndStore(apiCall), minute='0-59')
```

When I run this, the output is the following:

```
Start cron for:  A
Start cron for:  B
Start cron for:  C
C
C
C
```

The strange thing is that it appears to start it for A, B and C, but it actually starts a cron for C three times. Is this a bug in APScheduler? Or am I doing something wrong here?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This annoyed me for a while until I finally figured it out.  So much so, I created a stackoverflow account after **years** of lurking.  First post!

Try dropping the lambda (I know..., I went down that route too) and pass the arguments via args as a tuple.  I've used a slightly different scheduler below, but it should be easily adapted.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time   

def getAndStore(apiCall):
    # does a call to the api using apiCall as a value
    # and stores it in the DB.
    print(apiCall)

apiCalls = ['A', 'B', 'C']

apsched = BackgroundScheduler()
apsched.start()
for apiCall in apiCalls:
    print ('Start cron for: ' + apiCall)
    apsched.add_job(getAndStore, args=(apiCall,), trigger='interval', seconds=1)

# to test
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output is:

```
Start cron for: A
Start cron for: B
Start cron for: C
B
A
C
```

Comment: Best reason to open a StackOverflow account ever! Thanks a million!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
for apiCall in apiCalls:

    print 'Start cron for: ', apiCall

    action = lambda x = apiCall: getAndStore(x)
    apsched.add_cron_job(action , minute='0-59')
```

Comment: While this does work, the previous poster's answer should be preferred because not only is it simpler but the "args" parameter was added for this specific reason. Also, it won't work with persistent job stores or executors that require serialization.